# waitInterval configuration on msdeploy DeploymentProviderOptions

Tags: msdeploy

As part of our build and deploy code, we have timeout issues related to stopping and starting a service.

Here is the code that stops the service

```
public DeploymentChangeSummary StopService(WebPublisherParameters parameters)
    {
        var sourceOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions();

        var destinationEndpointOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions()
        {
            ComputerName = parameters.DestinationComputer
        };
        var destProviderOptions = new DeploymentProviderOptions(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.RunCommand)
        {                
            Path = "Net Stop " + parameters.DestinationName
        };

        using (var sourceObj =
            DeploymentManager.CreateObject(new DeploymentProviderOptions(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.RunCommand), sourceOptions))
        {
            return sourceObj.SyncTo(destProviderOptions, destinationEndpointOptions, new DeploymentSyncOptions());
        }
    }
```

We are having timeout issues and ulitmately a failed build because the service does not stop in time.

We tried configuring the waitInterval like this

```
destProviderOptions.ProviderSettings["waitInterval"] = 20000;
```

but realised that it was a read only configuration, so I was wondering if anyone could point us in the right direction to do this programmatically rather than using the command line option.

Thanks
Tapashya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set RetryInterval of DeploymentBaseOptions object. Edited code from the question.

```
public DeploymentChangeSummary StopService(WebPublisherParameters parameters)
{
    var sourceOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions();

    var destinationEndpointOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions()
    {
        ComputerName = parameters.DestinationComputer
    };
    var destProviderOptions = new DeploymentProviderOptions(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.RunCommand)
    {                
        Path = "Net Stop " + parameters.DestinationName
    };

    using (var sourceObj =
        DeploymentManager.CreateObject(new DeploymentProviderOptions(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.RunCommand), sourceOptions))
    {
        destinationEndpointOptions.RetryInterval = 2 * 1000; // Set wait interval to 2 minutes
        return sourceObj.SyncTo(destProviderOptions, destinationEndpointOptions, new DeploymentSyncOptions());
    }
}
```